# Is there a way to not display rows with duplicate ID in SQL?

Tags: sql, duplicates, boolean, sql-server-2014

This is my query

```
   SELECT * 
FROM O_SMFU WHERE (ID , SMFU_nNEWNAIYO) IN 
( SELECT ID , MAX(SMFU_nNEWNAIYO)
  FROM O_SMFU
  GROUP BY ID 
)
```

When ID is duplicated show only the row with max SMFU_nNEWNAIYO

but it gives me an error :

```
Message 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 49
A non-Boolean expression was specified near',' for a context that requires a condition.
```

data I have:

```
ID        SMFU_nNEWNAIYO
703            1930
703            1920
703            1910
705            1950
725            1900
726            1900
726            1900
886            1900
886            1900
```

data I want to get:

```
ID         SMFU_nNEWNAIYO
703            1930
705            1950
725            1900
726            1900
886            1900
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the database that you have.

Comment: thanks paul, I have added it. I am using sql server 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this query

```
SELECT id,MAX(SMFU_nNEWNAIYO)
FROM O_SMFU
GROUP BY id
```

This query will give you the data you want to get

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your SQL flavor (SQL Server) accepts this syntax, but in any case I would suggest just writing your query as a join:

```sql
SELECT o1.*
FROM O_SMFU o1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, MAX(SMFU_nNEWNAIYO) AS MAX_SMFU_nNEWNAIYO
    FROM O_SMFU
    GROUP BY ID 
) o2
    ON o2.ID = o1.ID AND
       o2.MAX_SMFU_nNEWNAIYO = o1.SMFU_nNEWNAIYO;
```

Another way to write your query on SQL Server:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM O_SMFU
ORDER BY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SMFU_nNEWNAIYO DESC);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have tried this query and it gave me two duplicate rows with the id 886 and
726 maybe because these two have duplicate id and SMFU_nNEWNAIYO also. how can I solve this ?

Comment: Add `DISTINCT` to the first select.

Comment: DISTINCT still did not solve the duplicated rows with id's 886 and 726, Kebis's answer works fine for me for now, but I appreciate your answer. I have a lot to learn from these two queries you sent.